# Symfony2 FOS RestBundle Test

Tags: php, symfony, testing, fosrestbundle

I`m trying to write some functional tests for a REST API, created using FOS Rest Bundle. 
The problem is that when I use the Symfony\Component\BrowserKit, symfony throws me the following error:
*{"message":"Unable to find template \"AccountBundle:Account:list.html.twig\". .. }*

The code that I run is:

```
$client = static::createClient();
$client->request('GET','/account');
```

When I run the request from the browser, it works fine.

Here is the controller:

```
/**
 * Get channel by ID
 * @Secure(roles="ROLE_USER")
 * @RestView()
 * @ApiDoc(
 *  resource=true,
 *  description="Get channel by id",
 *  section="Channel",
 *  output="Channel"
 * )
 */
public function getAction(Channel $channel)
{
    return array('channel' => $channel);
}
```

So when in test scenario, instead of returning the JSON tries to load the template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `$server` parameter of the `$client-request()` method to set the `Accept` header to `application/json`. `FOSRestBundle` has a listener that returns `JSON` only if the corresponding `Accept` header is received, otherwise it will search for the template corresponding to the controller.

`$client->request('GET', '/account', array(), array(), array('HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'application/json'));`